# How to remove Japanese non-meaning spaces in Swift 2.2?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I have a problem with String in Swift 2.2. I want to remove (or replace by "") the whitespace characters in a Japanese String like this:

> こんにちわ　　　　こんにちわ

Here is my code:

```
japaneseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{3000‌​}+", withString: "")
```

But it seems that impossible.

Comment: Why is it "impossible"? A character is a character. Your spaces are the `"\u{3000}"` character. If you want to remove them, remove them.

Comment: I'm a beginner, can you give me code of your solution?

Comment: Ok. thk u for your support

Comment: japaneseString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\u{3000}+", withString: "")
Why this one didn't work with me? @matt: can you give me some hints?

Comment: What's the part that doesn't work? Your code looks okay.

Comment: Downvoted for txtspk ("plz"), vandalising the title with "urgent", and not adding your code. I appreciate you might be a beginner, but we really do need more effort spent on questions.

Comment: Are you storing the result of that function in another variable?...

Answer (score 2):

I cannot drop back to Swift 2.2 (and I don't know why you're still using it), but the Swift 3 equivalent of your code works fine for me:

```
var japaneseString = "こんにちわ　　　　こんにちわ"
japaneseString = japaneseString.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{3000}", with: "")
// "こんにちわこんにちわ"
```

Comment: Irrelevant, but it should be こんにちは rather than こんにちわ.